# Complement of a convex compact set in $\Bbb R^n$ deformation retracts onto a sphere

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a compact convex set in $\Bbb R^n$. I want to show that the complement of $A$ deformation retracts onto a sphere. I proceeded as follows:

By translation we may assume $0 \in A$. Since $A$ is compact, it is bounded. So we may assume, by dilation, that $|x|<1$ for all $x \in A$. Thus, the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is contained in the complement of $A$. Define a deformation retract of $\Bbb R^n-A$ onto $S^{n-1}$ by letting $(x,t) \mapsto (1-t)x+tx/|x|$. Now we are only left to show the well-definedness of this homotopy, and I think I must use the convexity of $A$, which is not used until now. But I have no idea.

How may I have to conclude this proof?

Comment: To package up the argument in WhatsUp's nice answer, you can use that your translated, dilated $A$ is star-shaped with respect to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that $f(t, x) = (1 - t)x + tx/|x|$ is not in $A$ for any $t\in [0, 1]$ and any $x\notin A$.

Suppose it is not the case. Then there is $x\notin A$ and $t\in [0, 1]$ such that $f(t, x) = \lambda x \in A$, where $\lambda\in \Bbb R$ is the number $1 - t + t/|x|$.

If $|x| > 1$, then we have $\lambda \geq (1 - t)/|x| + t/|x| = 1/|x|$, hence $|f(t, x)| \geq 1$. This contradicts the assumption that every point in $A$ has norm $< 1$.

If $|x| \leq 1$, then we have $\lambda \geq 1 - t + t = 1$. But we also have $0\in A$. By convexity of $A$, the linear combination $1/\lambda \cdot f(t, x) + (1 - 1/\lambda) \cdot 0 = x$ is in $A$. This contradicts the assumption $x\notin A$.